# ¿Como puedo muestrar una imagen guardada en firestore en mi pagina hecha en react?

Tags: reactjs, imagen, google-cloud-firestore

Estoy haciendo mi blog personal y quiero mostrar imagenes como portada de los post pero no logro mostrarlas en mi componente de react. La imagen esta guardada en firestore. Agrego el codigo que estoy usando:

Esta es la primera parte del codigo donde obtengo la informacion en las coleciones:

```
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import PostCard from "./PostCard";
import db from "../FirestoreConfig";

class SectionPost extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    db.collection("fl_content")
      .get()
      .then(
        (snapShots) => {
          this.setState({
            items: snapShots.docs.map((doc) => {
              return { id: doc.id, data: doc.data() };
            }),
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log("error");
        }
      );
  }
```

Y esta parte es como intento mostrarla con la informacion que obtengo de la api de firestore, en lugar de tener una imagen local como sale en Card.Img, quiero ponerle la url de la imagen en el servidor:

```
function PostCard(props) {
  return (
    <Card className="post">
        <Card.Img variant="top" src={Image} alt="Imagen no encontrada" />
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>
            <h3>{props.titulo}</h3>
         </Card.Title>
          <Card.Text>
            {props.resumen}
          </Card.Text>
          <Button variant="primary">Leer mas</Button>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
  );

}
```

la informacion se la paso por props. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Cuando dices "la imagen esta guardada en firestore" te refieres a la url de la imagen o a la imagen en sí misma? De ser la imagen, almacenas los bytes o la codificación en base64?

Comment: la imagen, estoy utilizando flamelink para hacer un blog pero cargo la imagen desde alli y no se como obtenerla para mostrarla en la pagina

Comment: No conozco flamelink pero firestore no puede generar urls. Si no la convertiste a base64, entonces se almacenó como bytes y tendrás que convertirla a base64 para mostrarla. [Acá](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129486/set-img-src-from-byte-array) tienes un ejemplo

Comment: Debo mencionar que no se recomienda almacenar imagenes en Firestore a menos que sean iconos o algo similar. Lo recomendado es subir  las imagenes a [cloud storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) y guardar en firestore las url. Cloud storage tiene muchas ventajas sobre firestore, por ejemplo puede generar automaticante copias de varios tamaños por cada imagen que subas. Entonces al mostrarla puedes descargar la mas apropiada para ese tamaño de pantalla

Comment: Ah ok! Muchas gracias por los consejos. Estaba utilizando otro servicio para guardar las imágenes y cargarlas a la página. Ya se que puedo hacerlo desde el storege de firebase.